# c program to read file name when the file is dragged in to the exe

Tags: c, file

So i have a code which takes file name as argument and process the file. i have a driver main which waits for the user to give the file as input. when i drag and drop a file to the exe(console) i have to manually press enter to proceed. How can i read file name when file is dropped without having to press enter. This is the current code

```
int main()
{
    char string[120];
    puts("Spawning child with spawnl enter string");
    //read(STDIN_FILENO, string, 200);
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
    printf("string is %s", string);
    //spawnl( P_WAIT, "main.exe", "main.exe", string, "Arg1", "Arg2", NULL );
    return 0;
}
```

when i drag the file to console this is how console looks
Spawning child with spawnl enter string
"C:\Users\Shathish PC\Downloads\PRIYA.docx"
now i have to press enter to proceed. i want it to proceed as soon as i drop the file
Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to simulate an `EOF` or `'\n'` via whatever desktop you are using. Whatever drag-n-drop you are using should provide for that by redirecting the input to your program or appending a `'\n'` to it. Otherwise `fgets()` will be waiting for you to signal end-of-input either by providing a `'\n'` (which is what your pressing **Enter** is doing). The only other option is to use a non-blocking `select()` or `poll()` to poll stdin and reading input when it is ready on that file descriptor. That sounds like a reasonable alternative solution.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info. im still not able to get what youre saying how can i sumlate EOF or new line when a file is dragged. can u give me a sample code on how this can be implemented please and thank you

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dim, but why would you want to drag-and-drop a file to the console? Windows applications that accept drops don't normally run with a console, so I wondered what your design objective was.

Comment: Hi kevin. i have been asked to design a file system which takes file as input and writes the content to another file. But the file should not be given as a text(path name). The requirement is that user should drag and drop files in the stdin. Similar to MPV player. refer this link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jUXAaqfW08&ab_channel=Tenshi.

Comment: You cannot "drag and drop files in the stdin", because stdin is not an abstraction that supports a gui interface.  You need to properly clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you drop a file on an EXE icon in Windows, the program will be launched **with arguments**.

So you will need to use one of the expected ways to implement `main()`, please consult the standard for details.

For example, this little program simply lists all its arguments:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        printf("%d: \"%s\"\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You will use a variable of type `FILE*` to open a file with a provided name and to read from it. But this is another issue, shown in uncountable examples on the web.